# Editing a question another person asked to include my test results

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I was in the scenario where I didn't post the question, but I did run the code that the asker posted and got different results. I added the code I ran and the results to a comment (icky formatting), but was thinking: is it better for me to edit the original question to include my results?

If not, where do they go?

[Post in question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10971926/1427975)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular situation, I would **avoid** editing the other person's question with your results, since it should be up to them if they want to include it.  If you get a differing result, merely stating such in a comment would be sufficient.

If **you** asked the question:

If the new code and results don't yet answer your question, include the code and/or results in your question.  You can add a dividing section (`---`) after your initial question to include that.

If they do answer your question, you have the option of adding an answer yourself, or upvoting/accepting the answer that led you to the solution.

Comment: What about if the question was asked by someone else?

Comment: If the question was asked by someone else, it's up to them to add it.  I find it to be good form to do so, since it keeps all of the information in a neat place (comments don't do jack for formatting).